# stripe charge with existing consumer

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I use this code to make a payment and create a new customer on my stripe dashboard.

```
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
                "name" => $utente,
                "source"  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                "email" => $row['mail'],
            ]);
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
                "customer" => $customer->id,
                "amount" => $amount_cents,
                "currency" => "eur",
                "description" => $description
            ]);
```

The information such as the name or email the use to create a new customer, are taken from the dashboard of my site when a user is registered and connected to it.

This concern the user's first payment .php file.
on the second user's payment, the site redirect to a second .php file, where I need to add a second payment to the customer previously created. the problem is that if I keep the same code, on the stripe dashboard I find myself two equal customers. I don't know how to get the customer id when, when I redirect to the second payment page, as user information I only have the mail and the name .. how can I do?

I'll try something like that by searching on stripe api reference:

```
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::all([
            'email' => $row['mail']
        ]);
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            "customer" => $customer['data']->id,
            "amount" => $amount_cents,
            "currency" => "eur",
            "description" => $description
        ]);
```

but it give me the error

```
Must provide source or customer..
```

Comment: I suspect you just want `$customer->id`, not `$customer['data']->id`. I suspect `Customer::all` returns an *array* of customers, not just one, as well.

Comment: i tried also that but give me the same error.. anyway this is the $customer value: https://pastebin.com/PKEMADwN

Comment: i tried with $customer->data->id,$customer['data']->id and $customer->id but it give me the same error

Comment: You need to `print_r($customer)` to see what's in it. Again, I suspect it'll be an array, which means none of what you've tried will work.

Comment: i have used print_r to see the output(is that i have put on pastebin), and yes it is a multidimensional array, but idk how to take only a sub value of this array, also because I don't know if it is a specific stripe output and therefore has its own precise way of recalling values, on the reference it said nothing about it

Answer (score 0):

Listing customers will return an object with a data property. `data` is a list of customers so you'll need to index into that list and grab one of the customers before looking at their ID. It should look something like:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::all([
    'email' => $row['mail']
]);
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'customer' => $customer->data[0]->id,
    'amount' => $amount_cents,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'description' => $description
]);
```